# how can I get cursor output in JSON format?

Tags: android, eclipse, json

I am using cursor to retrieve data from SQLite which returns result in string format. Is there any way I can use cursor to get output in JSON format?

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert the contents of a `cursor` directly into a `JSONObject`, but you can do that with some logic.

for eg: Retrieve the `Strings` from the `cursor`, form a `String` which follows the `JSON` format, and use it to make a json object :

```
JSONObject jFromCursor=new JSONObject(string_in_JSON_format);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Vinay. I have code like this: String[] columns = {"name","Phone","city"}

Cursor c = db.query("tblContacts",columns, null, null, null, null, null) what next? is there any way now I get this result in JSON format?